# How to show Relationship for specific node in cypher neo4j with neovis.js?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neovis

Is there a way to get a relationships of specific node only in **neovis.js**. From the **Movie** sample limited the node to **2**. Now we have two movie nodes **The Matrix** and **The Matrix Reloaded**, want to show the relationship of the **The Matrix** node only, not for **The Matrix Reloaded**.

```
MATCH (n:Movie) WITH n limit 2 OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Movie{title:'The Matrix'})-[r]-(b) RETURN n,r,b
```

**Expecting a relationship like this image.**

[image: Expected Result]

But my query return relationship for both nodes.

[image]

How to achive this in neovis.js?

Comment: On your neo4j browser's settings there is a checkbox called `Connect result nodes`. Uncheck it. When checked, it displays all the relationships between the returned nodes, even if these relationships are not returned from the query